# Keras on Google Cloud ML does not seem to use GPU? Is it possible to make it work?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, keras, google-cloud-ml

I tried running Keras with tensorflow backend on cloud ml (google cloud platform). I find that keras does not seem to use the GPU. The performance for running one epoch on my CPU is 190 seconds and is equal to what I see in the logs dumped. Is there a way to identify whether a code is running in GPU or CPU in keras? Has anybody tried Keras on Cloud ML with Tensor flow backend running??

Answer (score 3):

Update: As of March of 2017, GPUs are publicly available. See [Fuyang Liu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43250888/1399222)

<s>GPUs are not currently available on CloudML. However, they will be in the upcoming months.</s>

Answer (score 3):

yes it is supported now.

Basically you need to add a file such as `cloudml-gpu.yaml` in your module with the following content:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  # standard_gpu provides 1 GPU. Change to complex_model_m_gpu for 4 
GPUs
  masterType: standard_gpu
  runtimeVersion: "1.0"
```

Then add a option called `--config=trainer/cloudml-gpu.yaml` (suppose your training module is in a folder called `trainer`). For example:

```
export BUCKET_NAME=tf-learn-simple-sentiment
export JOB_NAME="example_5_train_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"
export JOB_DIR=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$JOB_NAME
export REGION=europe-west1

gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
  --job-dir gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$JOB_NAME \
  --runtime-version 1.0 \
  --module-name trainer.example5-keras \
  --package-path ./trainer \
  --region $REGION \
  --config=trainer/cloudml-gpu.yaml \
  -- \
  --train-file gs://tf-learn-simple-sentiment/sentiment_set.pickle
```

You may also want to checkout [this url](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/) for the GPU available region and other info on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as K
K._set_session(K.tf.Session(config=K.tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)))
```

should make keras print the device placement of each tensor to stdout or stderr.